# WP7 PhoneApplicationPage EventHandler Problems

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, events, xaml

I merged 2 of my *Phoneapplication* Pages together. The first one shows, a Picture of the Song currently Playing, the Title and the Artist. And there is a Play/Pause Button in the Corner.

The second one was a Empty Page where I had a Gesture Handler in it. On the Empty Page the GestureHandler is working perfectly. But when i take the GestureHandler to the first page it doesn't work anymore. Not only the Gesture Handler also the Play/Pause Button doesn't work. And i dont see what could cause that the EventHandlers are not working..

These are my 2 Files:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="EnergyRadio.ChannelView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnergyRadio"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
 xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="696" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CustomButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="0">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
<!--LayoutRoot ist das Stammraster, in dem alle anderen Seiteninhalte platziert werden-->
<Grid Margin="0" x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--TitlePanel enthält den Namen der Anwendung und den Seitentitel-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical" Opacity="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <!--<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="ENERGY RADIO" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>-->
        <Image Margin="0,0,0,0" Source="/EnergyRadio;component/img/subpage_header.jpg" />

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="24,0,24,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <!-- <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>-->
            <Image Name="channellogo" Margin="0,0,192,0" Width="240" Height="76"  />
            <Button  Style="{StaticResource CustomButtonStyle}" Width="64" Height="64" Padding="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="368,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0">
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/EnergyRadio;component/img/WP7_Pause.png" Stretch="None" />
                </Button.Background>

                </Button>
        </Grid>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - zusätzliche Inhalte hier platzieren-->
    <phone:WebBrowser Name="wemfBrowser" Width="0" Height="0" Source="" />
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="24,24,24,0">
        <Rectangle Height="600" Width="450">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        </Rectangle>
        <Image Height="432" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="cover" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,432,0,0"  Height="30" Name="artist" Text="Artist" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,456,0,0"  Height="30" Name="title" Text="Title" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" Mode="Minimized" Opacity="1.0" >
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/save.png" Text="Get Ringtone" Click="getRingtone_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/delete.png" Text="Add Shortcut" Click="addShortcut_Click" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

My second file (Empty Page and Gesture Handler:):

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="EnergyRadio.RemoteView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnergyRadio"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot ist das Stammraster, in dem alle anderen Seiteninhalte platziert werden-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel enthält den Namen der Anwendung und den Seitentitel-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Energy Radio" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Remote" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - zusätzliche Inhalte hier platzieren-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Rectangle Height="600" Width="450" Fill="White">
            <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick" />
            </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Beispielcode zur Verwendung von ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Schaltfläche 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Schaltfläche 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Menüelement 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Menüelement 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I found out that i need to give Rectangle the Attribute FILL="white" in order for the Gesture Handler to work.

But the Rectangle has to be in the front so i can user the GestureHandler Everywhere on the Screen and it has to be transparent.

So anybody has an idea how i can make the Rectangle Transparent but still "clickable"? If i just remove Fill="white" it doesn't work.

Comment: The Solution to my first Problem was setting IsHitTestVisible="False" to IsHitTestVisible="True". Now i can Pause the Player with the Pause Button. But the GestureHandler still doesn't work.

Comment: Never mind found the Last Answer to my Question too.
it has to be: Fill="Transparent"

Comment: Please, add the solutions you found as an answer so you can accept it :)